# Scrape table from specific site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like to scrape a table from following site: https://www.skdd.hr/portal/f?p=100:303:5854770187957::NO:::

There are multiple tables (if you click on element below the table, on right).

Here is my try to scrape one table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# start session
session = requests.Session()
url_home = 'https://www.skdd.hr/portal/f?p=100:1'
session.get(url_home)

# get table as example
url = 'https://www.skdd.hr/portal/wwv_flow.ajax'
data_req = {"p_flow_id":"100",
            "p_flow_step_id":"303",
            "p_instance":"5854770187957",
            "p_debug":"",
            "p_request":"PLUGIN=M7SBVniUqc0DLJfAuTgJiU4MHK3a8SgwaEFyp1bXXeE",
            "p_widget_action":"paginate",
            "p_pg_min_row":"11",
            "p_pg_max_rows":"10",
            "p_pg_rows_fetched":"10",
            "x01":"45931411338999755",
            "p_json":"{\"pageItems\":{\"itemsToSubmit\":[{\"n\":\"P303_TRAZI\",\"v\":\"\"}],\"protected\":\"9jEsMgLfcyMaXhfZDGsf2Q\",\"rowVersion\":\"\",\"formRegionChecksums\":[]},\"salt\":\"180397212547794802609233030939086575065\"}"
            }
res = session.post(url, data=data_req)
bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="lxml")
bs.find_all("table")  # no table, but should be
bs.select('table')  # no table, but should be
```

EDIT: to see the table please: 1. accept the cookies 2. click English on top right 3. click 'registers' 4. click 'overview of issuers'.

Comment: Language on the site is very difficult to understand. Can you please post a URL where all these table are present as on opening the provided link i can't see any table on the page.

Comment: @Vin, I edit the question. You can see now hoe to get to the table.